# Problem is displaying frameset when connecting to django

Tags: python, html, django, frameset

there is a code #index.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows=100% >
        <frameset rows=76%,24% >
            <frameset cols=64%,36% >
                <frame name=reports src="reports.html" >
                <frame name=fg_log src=/****.py >
            </frameset>
            <frameset cols=64%,36% >
                <frame name=fp_log src=/********.py?fp=3&files=on >
                <frame name=ls src=/*******.py >
            </frameset>
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

at startup, simply by opening index.html through the browser - I see the data of the first frame
[image]

but if you start displaying the same index.html through django - I see 404 instead of hello world
[image]

and I also see an error in the terminal
[image]

I have not found the answer why this is happening and how to solve it, but I need to use frameset

```
urls.py
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

]
```

views.py

```
User = get_user_model()
@login_required
def index(request):
    template = 'core/index.html'
    return render(request, template)
```

template index.html I have attached above.
There are no problems with launching django

**addition to new comments**
the problem has not been solved yet

```
urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('reports', views.reports, name='reports-name'),
]

views.py
@login_required
def index(request):
    template = 'core/index.html'
    return render(request, template)


def reports(request):
    template = 'core/reports.html'
    return render(request, template)
```

index.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows=100% >
        <frameset rows=76%,24% >
            <frameset cols=64%,36% >
                <frame name=reports src="{% url 'core:reports-name' %}">
                <frame name=fg_log src=/cgi-bin/sendjobs.py >
            </frameset>
            <frameset cols=64%,36% >
                <frame name=fp_log src=/cgi-bin/fp_log.py?fp=3&files=on >
                <frame name=ls src=/cgi-bin/ls.py >
            </frameset>
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

reports.html

```html
hello world
```

Comment: can you please post you code for us to see the issue?

Comment: did you add something specifically you need? django's project is not small

Comment: When you open with browser, the browser simply finds **reports.html** in the same directory, so all is good.  With Django, folder structure is everything, and as long as everything was set up correctly, finding files is easy.  Answer: replace `<frame name=reports src="reports.html" >`, which does not tell Django where the template is, to 
 `<frame name=reports src="{% url 'core:index' %}" >`, which tells Django to go to the view with `name='index'`, then the view emits the actual template `template = 'core/index.html'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 Scenarios:

1. reports.html is a dynamic template file to be rendered and served by a django app/view via an url
2. reports.html is just a static file to be downloaded from server

**add 1)** if you want to download reports.html in the frame like any other URL from your app you need to install that path in the urls.py of your app like:

```
urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('reports', views.reports, name='reports-name'),
]
```

... create a view:

```
def reports(request):
    template = 'core/reports.html'
    return render(request, template)
```

... and add the url tag to the index.html:

(this is the django-way of using urls.py as a single point to define url-patterns and reference them by their name anywhere else)

```
<frame name=reports src="{% url 'core:reports-name' %}">
```

with above path, this will translate into:

```
<frame name=reports src="reports">
```

**add 2)** then it is a static file and should be treated as such like described here in django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!! unfortunately, after going through the first method, I did not solve the problem, I also see 404 in frameset.
Modified code added to the question

Comment: could you post the updated error message in console please. Interesting is the part about "reports".

Comment: thank you for your help, I think I figured it out, django turns out to have a lock on the display of frames. it was necessary to disable the setting in `"settings">"MIDDLEWARE">"# 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',"`

Comment: after that, everything started to be displayed, thanks again!

Comment: good point - never focused on that.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks
to "Razenstein" for the help, to solve the problem it was necessary to disable:

```
"settings">"MIDDLEWARE">"# 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',"
```